# Read integers from external data file to document programming code in LaTeX

Tags: listings, external-files, matlab

I am attempting to document my MATLAB programming code in LaTeX. For 
this, I use the `mcode` package, which defines the MATLAB `lstlisting` 
environment. With the commands

```
\newcommand{\mfileMain}{main.m}
\newcommand{\mfileMainFirstNumber}{\mfileMainFirstLine}
\newcommand{\mfileMainFirstLine}{26}
\newcommand{\mfileMainLastLine}{33}
\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=\mfileMainFirstNumber,
                 firstline=\mfileMainFirstLine,
                 lastline=\mfileMainLastLine]{\mfileMain}
```

I set the `firstnumber`, `firstline` and `lastline` parameters and use 
them to import a piece of MATLAB code into the LaTeX document with 
`\lstinputlisting`. However, when I add some code before the 
`\mfileMainFirstLine`, in this case 26, the code is shifted and the 
documentation is ruined. To fix this, I would have to update the line 
numbers.

I am trying to fix this issue by adding 'tracers' to my MATLAB 
program. I use the commands

```
filename=['lstinputlisting_line_numbers_' mfilename '.txt'];
fileID=fopen(filename,'w');
```

to create a text file in which I store the line numbers for which the 
code is documented using the command

```
dbstack_eval=dbstack;fprintf(fileID,[num2str(dbstack_eval.line+1) '\n']);
```

. This results in a text file `lstinputlisting_line_numbers_.txt` with 
content for instance like

```
53
62
75
91
```

in case I want to document four parts of the MATLAB program `main.m`.

What I want to do from here is simply use this line number data in the 
`\lstinputlisting` commands. Perhaps it is possible to store the line 
numbers in the `\newcommands{}{}`, or perhaps there is a better, more 
elegant way of doing it. In this way, the line numbers would update 
automatically in case I add new lines of code. Consequently, my LaTeX 
document would still be okay, saving me a lot of time not having to 
update the line numbers myself.

A minimum working example could look like the following. The LaTeX file 
`main.tex` would have the content

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{mcode}

% Data for the 'lstinputlisting' environments.
\newcommand{\mfileMain}{main.m}
\newcommand{\mfileMainFirstNumberA}{\mfileMainFirstLineA}
\newcommand{\mfileMainFirstLineA}{WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?}
\newcommand{\mfileMainLastLineA}{WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?}
\newcommand{\mfileMainFirstNumberB}{\mfileMainFirstLineB}
\newcommand{\mfileMainFirstLineB}{WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?}
\newcommand{\mfileMainLastLineB}{WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?}

\begin{document}
    In the code
    \lstinputlisting[firstnumber=\mfileMainFirstNumberA,
                     firstline=\mfileMainFirstLineA,
                     lastline=\mfileMainLastLineA]{\mfileMain}
    we calculate the .... 

    And in the code
    \lstinputlisting[firstnumber=\mfileMainFirstNumberB,
                     firstline=\mfileMainFirstLineB,
                     lastline=\mfileMainLastLineB]{\mfileMain}
    we calculate the.....
\end{document}
```

. The MATLAB file `main.m` would have the content

```
%% Line number output.

filename=['lstinputlisting_line_numbers_' mfilename '.txt'];
fileID=fopen(filename,'w');

dbstack_eval=dbstack;fprintf(fileID,[num2str(dbstack_eval.line+1) '\n']);    
%% Input to be specified by user.

alpha=10; % PDE parameter.
x_s=0; % Starting coordinate.
x_e=1; % End coordinate.
N_n=1e2+1; % (N)umber of (n)odes.
N_ip=2; % (N)umber of (i)ntegration (p)oints.

dbstack_eval=dbstack;fprintf(fileID,[num2str(dbstack_eval.line+1) '\n']);    
fclose(fileID); % Close the file 'fileID'.
```

Comment: This should be possible -- I try a solution

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just added a minimum working example to hoepfully make your life easier ;).

Comment: Where can I find `mcode`?

Comment: It should be possible by `\immediate\read... to \mMainFileFirstNumber` etc. But the code fails, due to some changes by `mcode` to `listings`

Comment: You should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You can find `mcode` at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package Click on Download Submission, extract the zip file and put `mcode.sty` in your LaTeX working directory.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use linerange markers in MATLAB comments? See subsection 5.7 in the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) manual.

Comment: @Adriaan: I already found it, but it's weird to google for it and hopefully finding the newest version then ;-)

Comment: @Jubobs Indeed the `matlab-prettifier` package looks great. But it does not solve the current problem, or does it? And concerning Section 5.7 in the listings manual....I don't really understand it :(... Perhaps it solves the issue. Could you perhaps take my minimum working example and adapt it accordingly in an answer here? Then everybody can test it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Adriaan See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, it would be simpler and more robust to just use *linerange markers* for `listings` in comments of your m-file. See the example below. I used the `matlab-prettifier` package instead of `mcode`, but the approach should work with either.

Basically, you define a prefix for those linerange markers with the `rangeprefix` key; here, the prefix I use is simply a percent character (`%`) followed by a space character:

```
rangeprefix=\%\ ,
```

Note that both of those characters must be escaped here (but not in your MATLAB code).
Then, in your code, you use a pair of descriptive strings to mark the start and end of each of the ranges of interest. In the example below, I used `param` and `endparam` for the first range of interest, and `param2` and `endparam2` for the second range of interest. Make sure to use

```
includerangemarker=false
```

if you don't want the markers themselves to appear in the output.

You can find more details about those linerange markers in subsection 5.7 of the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
foo=3
bar=5
baz=foo
foo=bar
bar=baz
% param
% first set of parameters
alpha=10; % PDE parameter.
x_s=0; % Starting coordinate.
x_e=1; % End coordinate.
N_n=1e2+1; % (N)umber of (n)odes.
N_ip=2; % (N)umber of (i)ntegration (p)oints.
% endparam
clear baz
% param2
% second set of parameters
beta=20;
N = 42;
% endparam2
\end{filecontents*}

\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  rangeprefix        = \%\ ,
  includerangemarker = false,
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[linerange=param-endparam]{sample.m}
\lstinputlisting[linerange=param2-endparam2]{sample.m}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure, what the 4th number is expected to be, but this reads the numbers and assigns them to macros.

Apart from this all, one should consider Jubob's comments ;-)

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{mcode}%

\newread\mylinenumbers

\newcommand{\mfileMain}{main.m}%

\def\mFileMainFirstLine{}
\def\mFileMainFirstNumber{}
\def\mFileMainLastLine{}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \openin\mylinenumbers=lstinputlisting_line_numbers_.tex
  \read\mylinenumbers to \mFileMainFirstNumber
  \read\mylinenumbers to \mFileMainFirstLine
  \read\mylinenumbers to \mFileMainLastLine
  \closein\mylinenumbers
}%




\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=\mFileMainFirstNumber,
                     firstline=\mFileMainFirstLine,
                     lastline=\mFileMainLastLine]{\mfileMain}

\end{document}
```

### Improved version

Use a separate command `\ReadinLineNumbers` just before the `\lstinputlisting` takes places, therefore updating the linenumber information.

In principle, this could be added to the \lstinputlisting` command directly, it would break for other calls of the command however.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{mcode}%

\newread\mylinenumbers

\newcommand{\mfileMain}{main.m}%

\def\mFileMainFirstLine{}
\def\mFileMainFirstNumber{}
\def\mFileMainLastLine{}

% This command assumes that there always triples for the line number information
\newcommand{\ReadinLineNumbers}{%
  \read\mylinenumbers to \mFileMainFirstNumber
  \read\mylinenumbers to \mFileMainFirstLine
  \read\mylinenumbers to \mFileMainLastLine
}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \openin\mylinenumbers=lstinputlisting_line_numbers_.tex
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closein\mylinenumbers
}%

\begin{document}

\ReadinLineNumbers

\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=\mFileMainFirstNumber,
                     firstline=\mFileMainFirstLine,
                     lastline=\mFileMainLastLine]{\mfileMain}

\ReadinLineNumbers

\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=\mFileMainFirstNumber,
                     firstline=\mFileMainFirstLine,
                     lastline=\mFileMainLastLine]{\mfileMain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\immediate` has no effect on `\openin` and on `\read`.

Comment: @egreg: Right: I copied some code for writing and forgot the remove `\immediate`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Looks good, but this does not work for when one wants to use `\lstinputlisting` multiple times for different pieces of code from one `main.m`, right?

Comment: @Adriaan: That feature was not in your question, right? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're absolutely right :(, my fault. That's why I just updated my question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I will add a solution for that ;-)