# Using \lstinputlisting to include portion of file using labels instead of line numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I know I can include a portion of a code file like so:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=XML, firstline=37, lastline=45]{source_filename.xml}
```

But the line numbers will change if I modify the code file. Is it possible to use references to specify the first and last lines? Basically I'm envisioning something like this:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=XML, firstline=\ref{tag-start}, lastline=\ref{tag-end}, escapeinside={@}{@}]{source_filename.xml}
```

With the portion of interest in the `source_filename.xml` file looking something like this:

```
<MyTag><!-- @\label{tag-start}@ -->
  ...
</MyTag><!-- @\label{tag-end}@ -->
```

Comment: Use range markers; see, for instance, [this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200128/21891), and section 5.7 in the [`listings` documentation](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Jubobs comment, I ended up with this:

### LaTeX file

```
\lstset{
  rangeprefix=<\!--\ ,
  rangesuffix=\ -->,
  includerangemarker=false
}

\lstinputlisting[language=XML, linerange=tag\-start-tag\-end]{source_filename.xml}
```

### source_filename.xml

```
<!-- tag-start -->
<MyTag>
  ...
</MyTag>
<!-- tag-end -->
```

This worked a trick, although I'll probably change my markers to not include hyphens.

Comment: XML provides a Processing Instruction in the form <?name string?> so I am using <?doc start?> and <?doc end?> (and <?doc ...?> lots of other values) where I define rangeprefix=\<? and rangesuffix as ?\> so that I don't have to use comments, which I keep for doing actual comments in the XML. However, I am having trouble using PIs in large scripts I am documenting (see separate question).