# minted or listings input a file between markers

Tags: listings, minted

Is it possible, using the `minted` or `listings` package to format
a file between or till a certain textual marker automatically.
E.g. consider a source file:

```
code
code
//marker
code ...
//end marker
code
```

I would like to input the code between the two markers
without manually specifying the `firstline` & `lastline`
as they can change during the project.

Comment: You can use `listings`'s arbitrary line-range markers for that. See section 5.7 in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more details, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200128/21891 for an example.

Comment: This feature has been [requested for `minted`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/76), and some form will be present in the next release. Basic functionality should already be possible using `fancyvrb` syntax, which is a bit ugly (hence the need for a nice `minted` wrapper); see the linked issue for an example.

Comment: Any news here? @G.Poore How is the status of this development?

Comment: @TeXnician Getting this to work properly in the general case is more complex than anticipated due to all the factors involved (regex, caching, handling line numbers, etc.). I think I've figured out how to do it, but it will have to wait on major revisions planned for `minted` v3.0. I don't have an estimate for when that will be released.