# listings "escapeoutsides"

Tags: pdftex, listings

I know, it's escapeinsides. But how can I show only the part of code? Not by linerange? But by "word" range?

For example i will show only code from `//<B>` to `//<qB>`

```
//<A>
class A{
public A(){
  System.out.println("Hello from A");
}
//<qA>

//<B>
class B extends A{
  System.out.println("Hello from B");
}
//<qB>

//<C>
class C extends B{ 
 System.out.println("Hello from C");
}
//<qC>
```

Comment: Use linerange markers; [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200128/21891) is an example.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. Yes, that's what I wanted. Just a small note to the solution. Does not work with \usepackage{babel}

Comment: If you have a problem with `babel`, ask a new question and post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).